# ¿Por que al recorrer un array con "ForEach" solo me muestra un elemento?

Tags: javascript

Sucede que tengo un sencillo programa que tiene que recorrer un array y colocarlo en un div que identificó y lo llamo.
El punto es que cuando se ejecuta solo se muestra como resultado el ultimo elemento del Array. Segun yo tendria que mostrarse todos.

```js
'use strict'

var videojuegos = ['Resident Evil 3', 'Silent Hill', 'Mario Kart', 'Portal 2', 'Katamary Damacy'];

var caja = document.querySelector('#caja');

videojuegos.forEach((item) => {
    caja.innerHTML = item;
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: gray;">
    <div class="container" style="background-color: white;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div style="display: block;">
                   <div id="caja"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo unico que debes hacer es modificar dentro del `forEach` la asignación que haces para que se vea de este modo:

```
videojuegos.forEach((item) => {
        caja.innerHTML += item;
    })
```

Para que:

- Hacemos uso de `+=` para que no vaya solo iterando los valores del vector sino que además de recorrerlos los asigne a la variable y los *vaya almacenando* de modo que en la última vuelta cuando obtiene a *Katamary Damacy* ya tenga almacenados los valores previos de las otras posiciones
- Te esta mostrando solo la última película por que el ciclo hace su recorrido leyendo cada valor de cada posición y asignando a tu `div` el último obtenido

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me sirvio mucho. Aun ando agarrando el modo de usar los operadores, soy nuevo aprendiendo JavaScript. Saludos